# Finder crashes log : libsystem_c.dylib

Tags: macos

Every minute two of our Macbook Pro's crash. On my logs I see :

```
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libsystem_c.dylib   0x00007fff970db541 __xvprintf + 106
```

sometimes it's thread 7 and other times :

```
Thread 10 Crashed:
0   libsystem_c.dylib   0x00007fff970db541 __xvprintf + 106
```

The full log can be seen here : 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22331148/Personal/crash_log.txt

I am running OS X Mavericks

Comment: Stack overflow is not the appropriate place to ask tech support related questions, you may be better served by http://apple.stackexchange.com, but it appears this is a problem related to Google Drive: https://discussions.apple.com/message/23667209#23667209

Answer (score 0):

Goto to your Google Drive preferences
UNCHECK "show file sync status icons and right click menu"

Solved the issue for me.